# Remove square brackets that don't have spaces between them

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to remove square brackets that don't have spaces between them, but keep square brackets that do. For example:

- Match these brackets and remove them: `[`please`]`
- Don't match these brackets and remove them: `[`help me`]`

Note: I want to match just the brackets, not the content.

I think that I need to use look ahead, e.g. `\\[(?!= )`. However, this only looks ahead to the next character, whereas I want to check that all characters between the square brackets are not spaces. What to do in this situation?

Comment: `Note: I want to match just the brackets, not the content` What makes you think you can do that? In a single match, you can't match something then skip ahead and match something else. Regular expression matching is a continuous process from left to right. You _could_ find the first [ then look ahead for non-whitespace chars then closing ] but you can't do any replacement of the downstream ] at all. And in fact, the match position won't advance for the next match, it starts right after the first [ you matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of `stringr` may be of use to you, it has a nice widget for testing out `regex` matching.

```
stringr::str_view_all(c("[please]", "[help me]"), "(\\[)\\S*(\\])")
```

matches `[`, then any number of non-space characters, then `]`, with the `[` and `]` as capture groups. I'm not sure what you want to do with them.

**Update:** To remove brackets, you actually want to capture what's inside and then substitute with it.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(c("[please]", "[help me]"), "\\[(\\S*)\\]", "\\1")
#> [1] "please"    "[help me]"
```

(capture any all-non-space characters between brackets, and substitute the entire string for the capture where found)

Comment: I was trying to match only the brackets, not the content inside them. Is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps if you hinted towards why you might be trying to do so, we could offer more suggestions. Do you plan to replace them? If so, they are captured in my answer and can be substituted with `\1` and `\2`. e.g. `stringr::str_replace_all(c("[please]", "[help me]"), "(\\[)\\S*(\\])", "\\1\\2")` changes just `[please]` to `[]`.

Comment: I plan to remove the brackets -- I've elaborated my intent in the main question. Sorry for being abstruse.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you're coming at it from the wrong direction.

Comment: This is one of those moment where my understanding got expanded into entirely new territory! Thank you very much!